# Duplicated data in Web SQL

Tags: javascript, html, web-sql

How can i make data not duplicated how ever id row inserted automaticlly

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS logins (Username, Password)');
});
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO logins VALUES ("Ahmed","123")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO logins VALUES ("Ahmed","123")');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS logins (Username UNIQUE, Password)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO logins VALUES ("Ahmed","123")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO logins VALUES ("Ahmed","123")');
});
```